# Generating and printing spreadsheets from C++

Tags: c++, spreadsheet

I'm rewriting an old application and I'm looking for some library to generate/modify spreadsheets and print them from C++.

I wrote the original application many years ago with Visual Basic 5 and it depends on Excel for printing tasks. I designed the tables with Excel, and I used to manipulate a hidden Excel instance from VB to modify and print them in my program.

Now, I need some tool to reproduce that functionality (printing) from my new C++ app.
It doesn't have to be with Excel, something else portable that avoids the dependency from an Office/OpenOffice would be great, but it is not mandatory.

I'm thinking on using latex as an alternative, but I can't find any suitable tool for generating latex code (I've tried calc2latex but it can't handle cell format very well), and before writing them manually I ask here for something better.

Comment: Searching both this site and Google for terms like "C++ spreadsheet" should get a number of hits. For instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928968/c-outputting-to-an-excel-file

Answer (score 2):

I realise you're not specifically wanting to use Excel, but if you were previously controlling it from VB using OLE you could try using VOLE in C++ to manipulate it the same way. If your other options don't bear fruit, perhaps this would be worth trying.

http://vole.sourceforge.net/

An ex-colleague used this for driving various OLE-friendly applications, including Excel I believe. He said it was pretty straightforward to use.

Comment: Thanks! I've just made a little test and it's really straightforward. I was searching in sourceforge, but I haven't seen this one. Keeping the excel's stuff is the easiest and fastest way. I can take it now and try to implement something else later.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://smartdb.dyndns.info.
It has got a spreadsheet engine for c++ developers.